# No class found MemorySafeUndeclaredThrowableStrategy Spring Security

Tags: spring-security

I currently have a spring mvc application which I'm trying to add spring security to. However, I can't use the `@PreAuthorize` annotation without getting the following error:

Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/cglib/transform/impl/MemorySafeUndeclaredThrowableStrategy

I'm currently using Spring Version 4.1.0 and Spring Security 3.2.5, which according to spring's documentation and other posts on here should work fine. 
There's also a sample on their github which appears to be using the same versions without issue.

Any ideas?

The PreAuthorize tag has been added to a Controller, cglib is in the classpath, yet still the same error message. Any ideas?

Comment: Do all the versions of Spring (i.e. artifacts that have a group id of org.springframework) match? Do all the versions of Spring Security (i.e. artifacts that have a group id of org.springframework.security) match? In maven you can determine this using mvn dependencies:list

Comment: They didn't match due to Spring Security being behind on versions, figured it out eventually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out it was version issues. Spring Security is currently at 3.2.5.Release, which I was using, but Spring was at 4.1.0. 
As of 4.0.2, some of the cglib classes have been removed. The solution was to go down to 4.0.1 in Spring, or use the 4.0.0.M2 milestone release for spring security.

Comment: It should work with Spring Framework 4.1.2.RELEASE as well. The key is to ensure that all versions of Spring Framework are the same.

Comment: Unfortunately that couldn't be done in this case. People had already started using features of Spring 4.0.1, and spring security  version 4 is only at milestone release atm.

Comment: I am working with **Spring 4.1.4.RELEASE** and works with **Spring Security 4.0.1.RELEASE**

Answer (score 0):

@PreAuthorize is implemented via AOP. If the method on which you put the annotation are not declared in an interface implemented by the class, Spring cannot use the default of JDK proxy, but uses CGLIB to proxy classes.

The error suggests you use class proxying, but do not have CGLIB in classpath.

Two ways to fix it :

- add CGLIB to classpath
- make your class implements an interface

BTW, you say you added @PreAuthorize to a RestController. `@PreAuthorize` annotation is more frequent in service layer. Normally, you use URL based authorization for what could exists in controller. The best way to fix the problem could be to move the `@PreAuthorize` annotation to the service class that should already be wired as an interface.

Comment: I see, the method I've added it to is a RestController which doesn't have an interface.
Shouldn't maven pull in this dependency if it's required?

Comment: Are sure GCLIB is required? No where in the release notes does it mention gclib, and the PreAuthorize examples mention nothing about having to implement an interface.
http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.5.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/

Comment: I added cglib to my classpath, but still no luck.